# Pascal, reading unknown number of integers

Tags: pascal, freepascal

My question is how can I read some number of integers that user enters on standard input, and place them in array.However I don't how many numbers user will enter and i can't ask him that? User enters numbers in one line.

Comment: Read user input as string, then use [WordCount](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/wordcount.html) and [ExtractWord](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/extractword.html) functions to get values count and each value. BTW It is only one of many solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this, but i was wondering if there is some simpler way, for example using ''while not eoln'' loop?

Comment: @lurker `while not eoln do begin Read(i); Write(i, '  '); end;` works fine (`i: Integer;`) except it does not allows spaces before `eoln`.

Comment: @Abelisto thanks that did occur to me after I posted my comment. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on comments there is three ways demonstrated:

```
program readmultiint;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
    StrUtils;

const
    CMaxValues = 3;

var
    s: string;
    darr: array of Integer;
    sarr: array [0..CMaxValues-1] of Integer;
    i, cnt: Integer;
begin
    // Dynamic array using WordCount
    Writeln('Enter values:');
    Readln(s);
    cnt := WordCount(s, StdWordDelims);
    SetLength(darr, cnt); // Allocate room for values
    for i := 0 to cnt - 1 do
        Val(ExtractWord(i + 1, s, StdWordDelims), darr[i]);

    for i in darr do
        Writeln(i);

    // Dynamic array usin EOLN

    SetLength(darr, 0);
    Writeln('Enter values:');
    while not eoln do
    begin
        SetLength(darr, Length(darr) + 1); // Expand array for next value
        Read(darr[High(darr)]);
    end;
    Readln; // Read <Enter> itself

    for i in darr do
        Writeln(i);

    // Static array

    cnt := 0;
    Writeln('Enter values:');
    while (not eoln) and (cnt < CMaxValues) do // Reads not more then CMaxValues values
    begin
        Read(sarr[cnt]);
        Inc(cnt);
    end;
    Readln; // Read <Enter> itself

    for i := 0 to cnt-1 do
        Writeln(sarr[i]);
end.
```

Feel free to use one of them or provide your own :)

PS: Some readings:

[Dynamic arrays](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array)

[Val procedure](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/val.html)

[for-in loop](http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop)

Answer (score 2):

Okay i have just one more answer i would like to add.Thanks all for your help this is code written based on suggestions.I added a line for writting array backwards just for you can see that it has readed well.

```
program backo;
 var niz:array [1..100] of integer;
  n,  i:integer;

begin
i:=1;
    writeln('enter elements of array');
    read(niz[i]);
    while not eoln do
            begin
                    i:=i+1;
                    read(niz[i]);
            end;
    for n:=i downto 1 do
    writeln(niz[n]);
end.
```

Comment: It's creative :) Good luck.